# When I click on a bar in a graph to drill down, it goes blank

Tags: internet-explorer, apex, fusioncharts

I have a bar graph that has worked fine for years. There were a few changes to the systems that I don't have control over and now when users click on the bar chart, it goes blank.

System: Windows 2003 server connected to a Linux server running 11g Oracle
Software: Oracle Apex 3.2 and Fusion Charts

Additional Information: Chart is in a frame on a page with other charts. All charts work fine on initial load. But when you click on the bar to drill down, that chart display area goes blank.

User community uses IE V8 or V11 and is enforced by IT. Issue happens in both browsers.

I have loaded developer mode and looked at all the data coming through it is all good.

**Goofy work around may indicate what is going on**
1. Load page and graphs look normal.
2. Click on bar in one of the charts to drill down and it blanks out the whole chart.
3. Right click in blank area where chart should be and select print. Then click Cancel button.
4. Chart shows up that is drilled down. *AND* That frame functions normally from that point on.

During these steps, I had the network tab in IE open on developer mode and clicked capture, nothing is being sent over the network when the right click, print, or cancel is pressed.

It is impractical to have users drill down this way, so any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the following information, so that I can assist you better ?

1) Are you using Flash version or javascript version of FusionCharts
2) Can you give me the chart configuration of your chart ?

http://www.fusioncharts.com/features/linkedcharts-for-drill-down/ Have you gone through this to create the drill down chart ?